# Regex how to match string that contains square bracket

Tags: regex

How to match a string like this :

```
firstword [foo = bar]
```

and

```
firstword
```

using 1 regex.

What I've tried is `(\w+)[\s]{0,1}\[(.+)\]` and by that I can only match the first one, I also tried by wrapping the last one `\[(.+)\]` with `[]*` to `[\[(.+)\]]*` and now I cannot match whitespace and '=' inside the square bracket.

Can you guys give a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like the last part is simply optional:

```
(\w+)\s?(?:\[([^\]]+)\])?
```

The `(?: ... )?` is an optional part without performing memory capture.

If the optional part also means there will always be a space, you can move the `\s` inside as well:

```
(\w+)(?:\s\[([^\]]+)\])?
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(\w+)\s*(\[.+?\])?
```

Test in Python interactive shell:

```
>>> re.match(r'(\w+)\s*(\[.+?\])?', 'firstword [foo = bar]').groups()
('firstword', '[foo = bar]')
>>> re.match(r'(\w+)\s*(\[.+?\])?', 'firstword [foo = bar').groups()
('firstword', None)
>>> re.match(r'(\w+)\s*(\[.+?\])?', 'firstword foo = bar').groups()
('firstword', None)
>>> re.match(r'(\w+)\s*(\[.+?\])?', 'firstword foo = bar]').groups()
('firstword', None)
>>> re.match(r'(\w+)\s*(\[.+?\])?', 'firstword').groups()
('firstword', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use non-qreedy quantifiers. In Perl extended notation:

```
s/  ^        # Beginning of string.  You might not need this.
    (\w+)    # Capture a word.
    \s*      # Optional spaces.
    (?:      # Non-capturing group. 
        \[       # Literal bracket.
        .*?      # Any number of characters, but as few as possible,
                 # so stopping before:
        \]       # Literal bracket
    )?           # End the group, and make it optional as requested.
 /
    $1       # The captured word.
 /x          # Allow the extended notation.
```

Modify this as necessary. Some engines use `\1` instead of `$1`.

Comment: This regex does not make the brackets optionnal.

Comment: Correct.  I shall edit my answer. On the other hand, if the regex didn't match, there was nothing to do anyway.